# Integração Angular com o Delphi

Tags: angular, delphi, cors, http-headers

Tenho um servidor Delphi DataSnap RestFul para ser acessado com front-end Angular, consegui aplicar GET normalmente porém na tentativa de executar um DELETE recebo o erro http failure response
Alguém saberia como resolver esse problema?

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.2:1738/datasnap/rest/tservico/natureza:1...' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão os navegadores não aceitam que seu site receba dados de outra fonte a não ser a mesma *origin*, CORS significa (Recursos provindos de origens cruzadas), por questão de segurança é desativado.

Então o que você pode fazer é liberar no servidor o [CORS Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) para *seu domínio* ou `*` para todos domínios..
Outra solução é fazer com que o Angular diga ao browser que o endereço da sua requisição é a mesma origin, você pode fazer isso criando um Proxy `.conf.json` no src do app:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://192.168.1.2:1738",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

E no comando de start deve adicionar o proxy a flag `--proxy-config`:

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve  --proxy-config ./proxy.conf.json"
```

Ou configure no ng serve do `angular.json`

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "NOMEDOSEUAPP:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      }
```

**Obs:** nas suas urls de requisição você utilizará somente `/api`/path